# How can I tell which API is using my resolver template?

Tags: aws-appsync

I have a resolver template that I use across several AppSync APIs using the Serverless framework. The same resolver template is deployed to each of my dev, stage, and production APIs.

I have a situation where this resolver template needs to know which AppSync API is calling it (dev, test, or production). I've checked out the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-identity) but didn't see any variables that would help.

Is there a way for the resolver to be aware of which AppSync API is invoking it without resorting to custom headers passed from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the stage isn't directly included in the `params` (first argument) your lambda function is invoked with, you can infer it by looking at the value of `params.request.headers.host`.

This will have the full url that your API was called with (for example: `abcdefgh.appsync-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`). Given that these are effectively constant, you can relate them back to your stage.